# Проблема при отправке http запроса

Tags: c#, html

Здравствуйте, есть  [сайт по исправлению ошибок в предложении](https://www.jspell.com/public-spell-checker.html)

После ввода текста, нужно нажать клавиши ( в зависимости что нужно: replace, raplace all, ignore....)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так вот, когда я мониторю fiddlerom запрос он выдает примерно такое:

```
fieldCount=1&learned=nullar%2Ciscuss%2C&proxyURL=%2Fjspellhtml%2FJSpellAd.jsp&styleSheetURL=%2Fjspellhtml%2Fjspell.css&guiLanguage=en&guiCountry=US&field_0=fieldvalue_0&fieldvalue_0=Spll+check+English%2C+French%2C+Spanish%2C+Italian+and+German.+Features+medical+dicionary%2C+word+counter%2C+character+counter%2C+post+to+Twiter+and+printing.+Perfect+for+homework%2C+blogs%2C+email+and+more.&hidePreviewPanel=True&confirmAfterLearn=False&confirmAfterReplace=True&directEdit=YES&ieMode=NO&enableLearn=YES&forceUpperCase=False&ignoreIrregularCaps=False&ignoreFirstCaps=False&ignoreUpper=False&ignoreNumbers=False&ignoreDouble=False&supplementalDictionary=&blankURL=about%3Ablank&language=
```

А как мне сделать такой запрос чтобы автоматически оно на каждую ошибку нажимало "Replace All"?

Comment: В чем проблема то? В том, чтобы отправить запрос или в том, что запрос сформировать? Чем отправляете? Покажите код, покажите что требуется и что есть, а то это непонятно из вопроса

Comment: Проблема не в отправке запроса, а в получении нужного ответа, что бы все replace all были сделаны

Comment: Для нужного ответа необходим нужный запрос. У вас он есть и вы его не можете отправить? В этом проблема?

Comment: @tym32167 смотрите, как всё на сайте, я ввожу текст, нажимаю spell check, fiddler мне показывает что выполняется POST /jspellhtml/JSpellAd.jsp HTTP/1.1, после чего когда я нажимаю на replace all ничего не происходит и не выполняется, мне вот интересно как мне достать уже обработанный результат?

Comment: Так а тег c# тут при чем? Вы пишете программу на c#?

Comment: @tym32167, да, обычный запрос на C#

Comment: Ну то есть у вас есть запрос в фиддлере и вам надо его отправить программно? Для этого есть класс ```HttpClient```, используйте его для отправки запроса. А все заголовки\тело запроса уже есть в фиддлере

Comment: @tym32167 все верно) запрос отправить, нет проблем) а как программно получить уже готовый результат, где проклацано на всё "replace all"???

Comment: Вы меня с каждым комментарием все больше путаете. У вас в заголовке написано, что проблема с запросом, а сейчас пишете, что проблемы с запросом нет, но есть прблема с ответом. Скриншот и предствленный урл мне ни о чем не говорит. Вам надо в результате сделать ```string.Replace()```? Или вам надо эмулировать нажатие кнопок в браузере? Ставите селениум или аналог, пишете сценарий, запускаете - пусть само клацается. Как закончит, считываете тем же селениумом результат. Что вы хотите сделать то?